# How do I diagonalize a matrix?

Tags: matrix

How do I diagonalize the following matrix:

```
m = {
     {-(d-1)*(d-2)*0,  25*c^2            , -(d-1)*(d-2)+0, 5*c  , -9/2c*(d-2)*C}, 
     {0             ,  -(d-2)*(d-1)*1/4  , -9(d-2)/2                           }, 
     {0             ,  0                 , -18                                 }
    }
```

When I type in the definition, I get the error:

> -(d-1)*(d-2)*0,25*c^2 is incomplete; more input is needed.

Comment: I've 'pretty printed' your matrix. Hopefully you can now see for yourself what went wrong?

Comment: Heh, that's a new error on me, but understandable.  Presumably the poster is from one of the green countries on [this map.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg)

Comment: Since this can be a sneaky problem for those of us originally from one of those countries to which @Michael referred, I just want to spell out the problem, to make sure that D0cpepper is aware of it. *Mathematica* uses a point as the decimal separator, not a comma. Instead, the comma is used as an element separator in lists. Your matrix therefore was malformed, because *Mathematica* interpreted your first row to have too many elements. If you change those commas to points, then you can evaluate e.g. `DiagonalMatrix[Eigenvalues[m]]` to obtain the diagonalized version of `m`.